If $A\in\mathcal{L}(H,H)$, and $\Re\sigma(A)<0$, why can we assume the numerical range is contained in the open left half plane?
I am reading the paper "How and why to solve the operator equation $AX-XB=Y$" by Rajendra Bhatia and Peter Rosenthal, and am specifically wondering about Theorem 7.1 which states:

If the spectrum of the Hilbert space operator $A$ is contained in the open left half plane, then there exists a unique positive invertible operator $X$ satisfying $AX+XA^*=-I$.

I understand most of the proof, except for this part:

As Williams [101] shows, without loss of generality it can be assumed that the numerical range of $A$ is contained in the left half plane.

I looked at the paper cited, which is "Similarity and the Numerical Range" by James P. Williams. I couldn't find any theorems that explicitly stated what Bhatia and Rosenthal claimed. My hunch is that this comes from Theorem 2 on the Williams paper, which states:

Let $A$ be an operator and let $C$ be an open convex set containing $\sigma(A)$. Then there exists an invertible linear operator $S$ with $W(S^{-1}AS)\subset C$.

Since the open left half plane is an open convex set, maybe the theorem above allows us to assume the numerical range of $A$ is contained in the open left half plane without loss of generality. i.e. if the numerical range of $A$ isn't contained in the open left half plane, find a similar operator whose numerical range is. Am I on the right track?
